# Как сложить время в Mysql

Tags: mysql

SELECT  DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL 4 Hour) AS `End` FROM `Log` WHERE `Id`= 3 - это только делает выбор, но как его записать в другой столбец,[image: бд] и есть какая либо автоматизация этого процесса чтобы после добавления оно само складывалось?
Таблица создана только для теста.

Comment: Приведите репрезентативный пример. Исходные данные: таблица такая-то (и может быть еще такая-то). С такими-то данными. Нужно чтобы из "этого" получилось "вот это". Пока что не понятно что откуда и куда Вы хотите добавить.

Comment: Date и Hour их нужно сложить в одну и вывести в End. 
Или к Date Interval использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть таблица `Table1`

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| date1 | time1 | result |
+-------+-------+--------+
|       |       |        |
```

Тогда запрос будет таким:

```sql
update Table1 set result = addtime(date1, time1);
```

- date1 - колонка типа datetime
- time1 - колонка типа time
- result - колонка типа datetime

**UPD:** Триггер, считающий и вставляющий значение при инсерте новой записи

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_time 
BEFORE INSERT ON Table1
  FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.result = addtime(NEW.date1, NEW.time1)
```

Comment: А есть ли возможность автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Можно создать триггер который будет следить за появлением новых данных и вычислять значение. Про триггеры можно тут почитать https://handyhost.ru/manuals/mysql/mysql-trigger.html

Comment: Я пробовал создать тригер но он не срабатывал, и задано было как автоматизировать этот процесс...

Comment: Если что-то пробуете и не получается, выкладывайте свои попытки. Тут тривиальный триггер. см. обновление.